# Outlook Delegate Access

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

Someone will be managing my calender. My problem is - if I choose the option for Delegation - "My delegates and me" so we both receive the full invites etc. if I accept the meeting - it does not update the request in my delegates mailbox (so they can essentially accept the meeting again).

However, if my delegate accepts the meeting, it will show in my Inbox for that invite, "Accepted by XYZ".

Is this how it should work, Outlook 2010, Exchange 2010.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work that way. A delegate in Outlook is someone who can view and manage another person`s mailbox items (calendar, inbox, tasks etc...). By having this priviledge on your mailbox, the only updates are performed in one calendar, yours.

Here is a link that explains more on the mailbox and calendar delegation: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/allow-someone-else-to-manage-your-mail-and-calendar-HA010075081.aspx

I hope this helps!